# SQL Join Three Tables; Return Values from Table 1 where all instances in Table 2 have the same field value

Tags: sql, inner-join, aggregate-functions, having-clause

I have three tables I need to join together. Specifically table 1 needs to join to table 2 and table 2 joins to table 3. I need to return values from table 1 where all instances of the values selected in table 1 in table 2 have a field of some value and then further selected by my join on table 3. It may be easier to present the example.

Table 1

| Order | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | A |
| 002 | A |
| 003 | B |
| 004 | B |
| 005 | A |

Table 2

| Box | Status | Order | Shipment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | 001 | 1 |
| 2 | X | 001 | 2 |
| 3 | X | 002 | 1 |
| 4 | X | 003 | 2 |
| 5 | X | 003 | 2 |
| 6 | Y | 004 | 1 |
| 7 | X | 004 | 2 |
| 8 | X | 004 | 1 |
| 9 | Y | 005 | 1 |

Table 3

| Shipment | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | C |
| 2 | A |

I need to select all orders from table 1 that are in status 'A' AND are tied to boxes in table 2 where all of the boxes for the order are in status 'X' and are tied to a shipment in table 3 that is in status 'C'.

My end result should return the following:

| Order |
| --- |
| 002 |

I have the following but it is not 100% accurate as Table2.Shipment can be a blank value. My real issue is difficulty in finding orders from table1 where all the boxes for that order in table 2 are in the same status.

```
SELECT order
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.order = table2.order
WHERE table2.order NOT IN
(SELECT table2.order FROM table2
JOIN table3 ON table2.shipment=table3.shipment
WHERE table3.status = 'A')
AND table2.order IN
(SELECT table2.order FROM table2
JOIN table3 ON table2.order = table3.order
WHERE table3.status = 'C') 
AND table1.status = 'A'
AND table2.status = 'X'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation, and filter on `t2` and `t3` with a having clause:

```
select t1.orderid
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.orderid  = t1.orderid
inner join table3 t3 on t3.shipment = t2.shipment
where t1.status = 'A'
group by t1.orderid
having max(case when t2.status <> 'X' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 
   and max(case when t3.status <> 'C' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked marvelously, appreciate the fast response as well!